# Hammer delete revisions that contain PII data

Tags: discussion, feature-request, pii

Well intentioned, but naïve users have posted Personally Identifying Information (PII) data in various questions in this site.  Oftentimes an ethical Sec.SE user will edit the post and obfuscate the data.... however the PII still exists in revision history.

I think it would be a good idea to be able to flagged and hammer delete revisions that contain PII so that they won't be visible in a google search.

Comment: Hey, how would you feel about spelling out 'PII' as 'Personally Identifying Information' in the first sentence? I have added a definition to the wiki tag.

Comment: @culix Good idea -Revised...

Comment: [naïve](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/na%C3%AFve)

Comment: What's hammer deleting? Deleting data with a sledgehammer? Or deleting it such that ordinary 10K users can't see it?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - Hammer deleting is so that normal 10K users can't see it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flag the question or answer with a description noting the PII and revision number. We'll take care of it or nag the SE staff to do so.